# How do I get the google-services.json file again, was accidentally deleted

Tags: android, google-signin

I was doing tutorials on Firebase and was required to create a config file, and download the google-services.json which I did. But after completion I felt the need to re-do the tutorials again, so i deleted everything of the old app, including the google-services.json file i had downloaded. Now when I try to create the json file again I get the message:

"The SHA-1 you specified is already used with the same package name for a different Android OAuth2 client."

I have tried deleting(shut down they say) the project on the Google Cloud Platform and still I cant create the file.

Hypothetically, if someone had created the file and somehow it disappeared or something, and they did not copy it to app how would they get it back, shouldnt there be a somewhere where one can download again? Where?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found answer

To download a config file for an Android app:

1. Sign in to Firebase and open your project.
2. Click cog icon and select Project settings.
3. In the Your apps card, select the package name of the app you need a config file for from the list.
4. Click downloadarrow google-services.json.

https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592

Answer (score 3):

Please check the image for better understand.

[image]